# ckeditor in a Bolt 2.0.x

Tags: ckeditor, bolt-cms

Can anyone explain how I configure and/or add plugins to the ckeditor in a Bolt 2.0.5 install ?

Bolt does a lot of mods to the standard creditor install, and while it used to be easy to add things, it seems in recent releases to have become a lot harder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about plugins, but you can set some options. The Bolt 2 config.yml file contains this:

```
# There are several options for giving editors more options to insert images, video,
# etc in the Wysiwyg areas. But, as you give them more options, that means they also have
# more ways of breaking the preciously designed layout. By default the most 'dangerous'
# options are set to 'false'. If you choose to enable them for your editors, please
# instruct them thoroughly on their responsibility not to break the layout.
wysiwyg:
  images: false
  anchor: false
  tables: true         # default is false
  fontcolor: false
  align: true        # Add 'align left', 'align right',etc.
  subsuper: false     # Add buttons for subscript and superscript, using <sub> and <sup>
  embed: false        # allows the user to insert embedded video's from Youtube,
```

You can see that I've changed the default for the 'tables' option, and it worked fine.